# I'm getting that query is not a function

Tags: node.js, graphql, prisma

## Edit01

I'm running the command `prisma deploy` when the command finishes executing, all queries are visible in the file `src/generated/graphql-schema/prisma.graphql` except the query `listProdutos` does not appear in the file.

is configured this way:

Resolvers/Query.js

```js
function listProdutos (_, args, ctx, info) {
  const userId = getUserId(ctx) 
  return ctx.db.query.produtos({
    where: {
      OR: [
        {
          user: {
            id: userId
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, info)
}
```

schema.graphql

```js
type Query {
  listProdutos: [ Produto! ]!
}
```

I have the following error:

```js
{
  "data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "ctx.db.query.produtos is not a function",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "listProdutos"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I put the project in git if needed:

https://github.com/Denis-String/lavacar-back

Answer (score 0):

Your query `listProdutos` is your own schema.graphql query name, but is not the query generated by prisma. Your resolver should look like this:

```
function listProdutos (_, args, ctx, info) {
  const userId = getUserId(ctx) 
  return ctx.db.query.produtos({
    where: {
      OR: [
        {
          user: {
            id: userId
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, info)
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the same error, you would have another idea, no mutation or query is being created, all the new functions I'm doing are returning this error

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the problem for me:

```
ctx.db.produtos
```